# Surjection in compact-open topology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $Z$, $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous surjection then is the induced map $g \to f\circ g$ from $C(Z,X)$ to $C(Z,Y)$ is continuous.  But is it still a surjection?

My issue is that it's not clear if it has a right-inverse...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many cases, $f_\ast: C(Z,X)\to C(Z,Y)$, $g\mapsto f\circ g$ is not surjective: Put $Z=Y$ and $h=id_Y \in C(Z,Y)$, then $h$ is in the range of $f_\ast$ only if $f$ has a right inverse.

Comment: So the sufficient condition is for $f$ to have a *continuous* right-inverse?

Comment: If $f$ has a right inverse $r$ then $g=f\circ(r\circ g)$...

Comment: Yes, of course, Flabby.

Answer (score 5):

Let $X = Y = S^1 = \mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z}$ be the circle and let $f \colon X \to Y$ be given by $f(t) = 2t$ which is continuous and surjective.

There exists no $g \in C(S^1,X)$ such that $f \circ g = \mbox{Id}_{S^1}$, as $f$ induces the doubling map on $\pi_1$.